# VBA look if value in array is in range

Tags: excel, vba

[image: values]

i create an array with the information above.

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F" & Range("F1").End(xlDown).Row).Value
```

Now i want to look in a range, if a value from array is in the range.
if yes than change the color for this matching cell.

```
Set ws = Workbooks("test.xlsx").Worksheets("test")

For i = 2 To Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    
        If arr(j) = Cells(i, 7).Value Then Cells(i, 7).Interior.color = RGB(180, 198, 231)
            
    Next
    
Next
```

i get a type mismatch error when starting the second loop

Comment: `arr` is a 2D array, even it is extracted from a column. You should use `arr(j, 1)`. But it is strange to compare an array with a range cell. I mean, in terms of making the code faster. You should use a larger array `"F2:L" & Range("F1").End(xlDown).Row)`.  And compare `arr(j, 1)` with `arr(j, 7)`. The most lost time comes from coloring the interior **for each cell**, once at a time. You should place these cells in a `Union` range and color **all of them**, at once, at the code end...

Comment: Is `Workbooks("test.xlsx").Worksheets("test")` the **active sheet**? Otherwise, your code has a problem related to miss-qualifying the used ranges.`Range("A2")` and `Cells(i,7)` refer the active sheet. That's why I supposed on my above comment that the used array should be extended. If not, you should use two such arrays. To make the code faster, I mean. If it should refer `ws` set for nothing, you should use `ws.cells(i, 7)`, `ws.Range("A2")`...

Answer (score 0):

If your code is in the same workbook as the workbook in which you want to search, then the workbook test.xlsx must be saved as test.**xlsm** .

Answer (score 0):

arrays built from ranges are 2D, even if only 1 column of data.
The following Works:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    
    arr = ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F" & Range("F1").End(xlDown).Row).Value
    'Set WS = Workbooks("test.xlsx").Worksheets("test") 'Your Worksheet
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'My worksheet
    
    For I = 2 To Range("G2").End(xlDown).Row
        For J = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            If arr(J, 1) = Cells(I, 7).Value Then Cells(I, 7).Interior.Color = RGB(180, 198, 231)
        Next
    Next
    
End Sub
```

[image: Example]